# Using append command to update line chart in Lightning server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, lightning

I want to visualize some streaming data using local [Lightning server](http://lightning-viz.org/setup/#local-server). I created a simple Scala test, which created a line chart that I can access at `http://localhost:3000`. The problem is that when I use `viz.append(newdata)` in order to update the existing line chart, this new data is not sent to the server and the graphic remains the same. If, however, I do `lgn.lineStreaming(Array(Array(1.0))`, then the new line chart is created.
So, what's the problem with updating the streaming line chart in Lightning?

```
import org.viz.lightning._

var viz: Visualization = _
//...
val lgn = Lightning(host="http://localhost:3000")
lgn.createSession("streamingtest")

// initialization
val series = Array.fill(1)(Array.fill(1)(r.nextInt(1)))
viz = lgn.lineStreaming(series)

// ...

// adding new data (THIS DATA IS NOT SENT TO THE SERVER)
val newdata: Map[String, Any] = Map("1" -> 1.0)
viz.append(newdata)
```

Comment: why the tag 'spark-streaming' ? I don't see relation.

Comment: @maasg: you are right, the relation is not explain in this question. but the idea is to use `lineStreaming` with spark steaming data.